# how to make pycharm use the packages I've downloaded through pip

Tags: python, pycharm

I've been downloading packages through cmd but whenever I import the library pycharm doesn't find it
and I don't want to download libraries whenever I make a new project
what should I do

downloading the libraries through cmd but pycharm doesn't read them
is it about the path?
I've including the path when I re-install python

Comment: How have you been downloading(?) the packages? Why not use `PyCharm` to install them? You would then be sure they were available in the correct versions of `Python`.

Comment: You probably have multiple python interpretor installed, or maybe a venv. You can use the pip utilitary from the python interpretor you're using, change your code interpretor to use the same as the one used by pip by default, or install your dependancies directly from the pycharm integration.